# Ubuntu 20 freezes when I press the Windows key

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using Ubuntu 20 on an ASUS laptop.  Earlier, I could press the Windows key and type in the (first few letters of an) application name before launching it.  Now, when I press the Windows key, the system just freezes. I am able to restore the applications by pressing Alt+F2 and r, but I'm not able to search for applications and launch them.

I saw online that this problem could be due to Workspace Grid, but how do I uninstall this software?  I have Tweaks installed on my system.

Comment: I'm not sure how Workspace Grid got installed or whether it is installed.  I did install gnome-tweaks (using "sudo apt install gnome-tweaks"), and the Tweaks utility does have a Workspaces tab (which lets you choose Dynamic vs Static Workspaces, and other things).

Comment: @pomsky 
I'm not sure how Workspace Grid got installed or whether it is installed. I did install gnome-tweaks (using "sudo apt install gnome-tweaks"), and the Tweaks utility does have a Workspaces tab (which lets you choose Dynamic vs Static Workspaces, and other things).

Comment: The 'Workspaces' tab in Tweaks is unrelated to the 'Workspace Grid' extension. Check in the 'Extensions' tab in Tweaks whether Workspace Grid is installed.

Comment: @pomsky  In Tweaks, under Extensions, the Workspace Grid app is not mentioned. The Workspace matrix option is enabled. Is there any way to search for and launch apps using the keyboard in some other way?